# fuzzy grouping similar strings, from a large list of strings, with custom rules for similarities

Tags: python, string, recursion, group-by, grouping

From a **large **list of sentences, I need to group them by similarities, without using difflib or fuzzyset, but having specified a custom rules for "similarities".

My algorithm works with small list, however it takes too long for large ones.
Also, I believe it should be recursive, instead of iterative, because some results are odd.

How can I improve it to work faster on large lists?

p.s: this is also slow, and it does not allow duplicates as it uses dictionary: [Grouping similar strings together from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56603572/grouping-similar-strings-together-from-a-list)

Here is my attempt:

```
# custom similarity rules
def fuzzyMatch(w1,w2):
    #print(w1, ':', w2)
    score = 0
    
    lastword1 = w1.split()[-1]
    lastword2 = w2.split()[-1]
    if lastword1 == lastword2: score+=.5
    
    if score < .5: return score
    
    inits1 = [i1[0] for i1 in w1.split()[:1]]
    inits2 = [i2[0] for i2 in w2.split()[:1]]
    score = sum([score+.1 if i in inits2 else score-.1 for i in inits1])
    
    return score

# grouping algorithm
def fuzzyGroup(words):
    output = []
    for word in words:

        #append first word
        if(len(output)==0):
            output.append([word])

        else:
            for i in range(0,len(output)):
                
                # check similarity
                score=fuzzyMatch(word,output[i][0])

                # if no match
                if(score<0.5):
                    if(i==len(output)-1):
                        # append into separate group
                        if not any([word in o for o in output]):
                            output.append([word])

                # if match
                else:
                    output[i].append(word)
                    
    return output

input_list= ['okushka', 'm misha', 'p valeri', 'm misha', 'o misha', 'p a valeri', 'o okushka', 'o olya', 'olya olya', 'o ol olya', 'misha', 'j okushka']

print('input:',input_list, '\n')

sorted_list = sorted(input_list,key=lambda x: x.split()[-1])

print('sorted:', sorted_list, '\n')

grouped_list = fuzzyGroup(sorted_list)

print('grouped:', grouped_list, '\n')
```

Output:

```
grouped: [['m misha', 'm misha', 'misha'], ['o misha'], ['okushka', 'o okushka'], ['j okushka'], ['o olya', 'olya olya', 'o ol olya'], ['p valeri', 'p a valeri']]
```

Desired output:

```
grouped: [['m misha', 'm misha'], ['misha'], ['o misha'], ['okushka'], ['o okushka'], ['j okushka'], ['o olya', 'olya olya', 'o ol olya'], ['p valeri', 'p a valeri']]
```

And it must work with huge lists.

Comment: Hi! Interesting question. How large is "large"? Give numbers. As a minor optimisation, I suggest replacing `w1.split()[-1]` with `w1.rsplit(maxsplit=1)[-1]` so it only splits the last word.

Comment: Wait, ignore my previous suggested optimisation. First you do `lastword1 = w1.split()[-1]`, then you do `inits1 = [i1[0] for i1 in w1.split()[:1]]`. Note how you call `w1.split()` twice for no reason. Just call it once, and assign the result to a variable: `words1 = w1.split(); lastword1 = words[-1]; inits1 = [i1[0] for i1 in words1[:1]]`

Comment: As another minor optimisation: never use brackets `[ ]` inside of a call to `sum( )`. That is, `score = sum([score+.1 if i in inits2 else score-.1 for i in inits1])` can be replaced by `score = sum(score+.1 if i in inits2 else score-.1 for i in inits1)`. The only difference between the two are the brackets `[ ]`, but it's actually much more performant without the brackets.

Comment: Though, are you sure you want `score = sum(score+.1 if i in inits2 else score-.1 for i in inits1)`, which looks very suspicious to me, and not simply `score = score + sum(.1 if i in inits2 else -.1 for i in inits1)`?

Comment: As another optimisation: The membership operator `in` is very fast to test membership in a set, but very slow to test membership in a list. In your code, `inits2` is a list, so testing `if i in inits2` is very slow. I suggest making `inits2` a set rather than a list. Replace `inits2 = [i2[0] for i2 in w2.split()[:1]]` with `inits2 = { i2[0] for i2 in w2.split()[:1] }` and boom, big optimisation.

Comment: Wait, are you sure your definition of `inits2` is correct? `w2.split()[:1]` is just the two first words of the sentence.

Comment: Okay, here is an important optimisation that you can make. In function `fuzzyGroup`, the only place you use the fuzzy score is in `if(score<0.5):`. Note how the only thing you care about is whether the score is less than 0.5 or not. You don't care about the actual exact value of the score. So there is no point in computing the exact actual value of the score. You can just replace your scoring function with `def fuzzyMatch(w1, w2): if w1.rsplit(maxsplit=1)[-1] == w2.rsplit(maxsplit=1)[-1]: return 0.5     else: return 0`

Comment: Note, it looks like your fuzzyMatch function is not symmetric? For instance, the value of `fuzzymatch('aaron eats apple', 'aaron ate apple')` is not the same as the value of `fuzzymatch('aaron ate apple', 'aaron eats apple')`

Comment: Hi @Stef thank you so much for your answers. The suggestions are great! The list is over 900,000 length. So I am not sure how long this will take to use this approach with such a large amount of strings... I am using 'inits2 = {i2[0] for i2 in w2.split()[:1]}'  in order to test whether initials are similar.

Comment: @Stef perhaps instead of using float as a score, using a Boolean value, would also improve the performance? `if not fuzzyMatch(a,b): continue`. Or This is useless for such a large list of data?

Comment: Yes, avoiding float could make it marginally faster. However, what would be a huge improvement is if you can map each string to a "representative value" and group by representative value without using the comparison function `fuzzyMatch` at all. Comparing 2 by 2 is much slower than mapping each string to one representative value. For instance, consider: `def fuzzyGroup(sentences):    d = {};    for s in sentences:        d.setdefault(s.rsplit(maxsplit=1)[-1], []).append(s);    return d`. This will be much, much faster.

Comment: @Stef thank you for your suggestion. I could also use `grouped_list = groupby(sorted_list, key=lambda elem: elem.split()[-1])`
`grouped_list = [[item for item in data] for (key, data) in grouped_list]`, and it will give me the same and fast result. The problem is that I cannot define more rules for grouping logic, such as also comparing by initials. Or can I?

Comment: If your concern is speeding things up for a very large list, beginning by grouping fast is a good idea. You can still refine later. Once you have a bunch of small groups that are mostly right thanks to the simple rule, you can check inside each group and see if some elements of this group should be excluded from the group because of the more complex rule. So: Step 1) Group fast by the simple rule. Step 2) Look at each group and apply the complex rule.